# Was Naruto controlled by the Nine Tailed Fox?

Tags: naruto

In the anime (Episode 133), when Naruto turns into the Nine Tailed Fox for the first time during his fight with Sasuke, Sasuke comments that the chakra has its own mind.

Was he controlled by the beast or was it the other way round?

Comment: Which episode...?

Comment: @AnkitSharma its from episode 133 I guess.

Comment: As far as I know (which is not so much by the way), Naruto indeed was controlled by the Nine Tailed Fox, because the first time he was able to control himself and come back from his evil and destructive possession was during his fight with Pein.

Comment: @SayantanSantra first of all, Naruto was NOT able to control himself, his dad just closed the seal to stop Kyuubi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During his fight with Sasuke Naruto is seen to be in his Version 1 of the Nine Tails cloak. According to the [Naruto Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki), Naruto has very little control over his actions. It is not until he enters the Version 2 form of the Nine Tails cloak that he loses complete control.

This is Naruto during the fight with Sasuke at The Valley of the End in the Version 1 form:

[image]

This is the Version 2 form where he loses complete control:

[image]

> In Version 1 transformations, Naruto had only the briefest of control
>   of his own actions. If he fell deeper into a rage, Naruto could slip
>   into Version 2, losing himself to Kurama's negative influence and
>   going berserk, requiring outside help to suppress the fox's
>   chakra.

Comment: the frequency of Naruto going nine tails mode increases in shippuden. He loses control easily. Why?

Comment: I wouldn't say that he loses control easily. He only loses control during tough fights like against Pain or Orochimaru.

Answer (score 1):

I think he is not controlled by the kyuubi, he just loses his mind for the rage, like anyone that gets really really angry. Kyuubi just speeds up the process of getting angry and will take control over Naruto just after he gets the nine tailed and complete kyuubi's form.